# Suppress subdirectory from Wordpress Multisite primary URL

Tags: multisite, htaccess, directory, wp-config

I just installed WordPress Multisite (version 4.7.2) in a subdirectory of my primary domain (`site1.com/wordpress`), and I've configured multisite to use subdirectories for all other sites.  I understand that Wordpress will not allow a change to the primary site's URL to remove the `/wordpress` portion of the URL because of how it handles permalinks.  But is there a way to suppress the `/wordpress` from my URLs in .htaccess or a redirect in cPanel?

Comment: Have you read up on [Giving WordPress its Own Directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)?